# I need to get Ionic and Vue to work together

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ionic-framework, npm

Trying to create and run my first app with the Ionic framework with Vue.JS and getting the following error with Vue service when i run the command

```
c:\myApp>npm run serve
```

**Error** i get is as follows

```
> ionic-app-base@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path c:\myApp
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-23T05_31_33_782Z-debug.log
```

The log file is as follows:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'serve'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.14.0
2 info using node@v16.2.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 12ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:c:\myApp\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\mcbai\.npmrc Completed in 2ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 2ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 20ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 20ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 7ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 3ms
22 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 4ms
23 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
25 timing npm:load Completed in 51ms
26 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 5ms
27 timing command:run-script Completed in 120ms
28 verbose stack Error: spawn bash ENOENT
28 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
28 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
28 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
29 verbose pkgid ionic-app-base@0.1.0
30 verbose cwd c:\myApp
31 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
32 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
33 verbose node v16.2.0
34 verbose npm  v7.14.0
35 error code ENOENT
36 error syscall spawn bash
37 error path c:\myApp
38 error errno -4058
39 error enoent spawn bash ENOENT
40 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
41 verbose exit -4058
```

When I check for the files mentioned, they are definitely in those locations

**Package.json** file from the project

```
{
  "name": "ionic-app-base",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is incomplete information.. first, why using npm run serve.. 2nd is Ionic-CLI installed globally..  and so much more.. can you share your package.json file details

Comment: Im totally a n00b and going by the Ionic help doc:

Comment: Just edited the original post with the package.json

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using the wronge Ionic command to create / run the Ionic project..

To Install Ionic Locally on your machine use:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

To start a New app navigate to the folder where you want the app to be created using the cmd and run

```
ionic start AppName
```

Once the app is created with the above command open it with your code editor and use the following cmd to run that app.

```
ionic serve
```

There is no such command as `npm run serve` to start or run an Ionic project. The reason I asked you to put your `package.json` in the question to understand if your installation failed with any missing packages which was overlooked but that doesn't look like it your project was created *okay*

Comment: at new SubprocessError
(C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:41:23)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:130:27)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit
(C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)

Comment: Got the above error when running ionic Start myApp

Comment: Ensure your NodeJs version is 14.x and you have npm 7 installed, any old version you will get an error, and Having nodejs with an odd version number in not recommended..

Comment: NPM 7.14.0 , Node 16.2.0